# How do I block an email address in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I need to block an external email address in postfix from sending me emails. This is an external email address of a third party domain name that I'm not controlling.

The reason why I need to block it is because they have something misconfigured and I'm getting a message saying "Warning, your message has not being delivered yet", every second or so. I already contacted their tech support, but they are taking a long time to fix it and in the meantime, my server and my users are suffering.

I tried doing this. In my mail.cf I added:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, permit
```

and in /etc/postfix/sender_access I added:

```
mailfilter@iomart.com REJECT
```

I run

```
postmap hash:sender_access
```

and restart postfix, but it seemed to have no effect.

I also tried:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

in the main.cf, which fails with this error:

```
postfix/smtpd[2144]: fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit
```

Trying:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, permit
```

gave me the same error.

Comment: you need to block the address you are trying to send to or receive from? Sorry, a little bit not clear.

Comment: @DanilaLadner it's an external email address, a sender that is not me.

Comment: Right, so that external email is sending you emails you want to block for your users?

Comment: @DanilaLadner yes.

Comment: In my experience the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` only affects mail based on `return path`, not MAIL FROM header as it says in the docs.  Not sure if this is a bug or what.  I tried spoofing an email to my server that should have been rejected by setting `from` in the header and it had no effect.  When i added the `-f` flag to sendmail to specify return path it successfully rejected my email.

Comment: @billynoah how correct you are.  took me several hours to figure this out.  Put simply, `smtpd_sender_restrictions` will only *block* mail based on its `Return-Path` header *NOT* its `From` header.  So if your `smtpd_sender_restrictions hash:/etc/postfix/block` contains `a@b.com REJECT` mail with `From: a@b.com` will *NOT* be rejected; rather, *only*  mail with `Return-Path: a@b.com` will be blocked (!!)  Arrrrgh.

Comment: And so, is there any solution to block the From rules?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Laurentio Roescu, the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` *should* work. Only I do not think that was what was intended. The sender is the person sending emails from your server. Not the sender from the other side.

So you indeed wanted to use the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access ...`, but as mentioned in the documentation, this is overridden by `smtpd_relay_restrictions` if you use it.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions

> Optional restrictions that the Postfix SMTP server applies in the context of a client RCPT TO command, after smtpd_relay_restrictions. See SMTPD_ACCESS_README, section "Delayed evaluation of SMTP access restriction lists" for a discussion of evaluation context and time.
>
> With Postfix versions before 2.10, the rules for relay permission and spam blocking were combined under smtpd_recipient_restrictions, resulting in error-prone configuration. As of Postfix 2.10, relay permission rules are preferably implemented with smtpd_relay_restrictions, so that a permissive spam blocking policy under smtpd_recipient_restrictions will no longer result in a permissive mail relay policy.
>
> For backwards compatibility, sites that migrate from Postfix versions before 2.10 can set smtpd_relay_restrictions to the empty value, and use smtpd_recipient_restrictions exactly as before.

So instead you would do:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = ...
    ...
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
    ...
```

That way it should be taken in account as expected. (The ... represent other options, be sure to place this check at the right location in the list.)

Comment: I have Postfix 3.3 running and wondered why this does not work...

Comment: @busythomas
On my end I also have `check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients` and the `bad_recipients` file includes email addresses with `REJECT`. One place where I had problem was a website that would send emails and those were accepted... so I added a test in my website code to verify the email against those in `bad_recipients` because in that case it would not be received from those people!

Comment: ooops, found it, I misread the "check_sender_access" part where I had "check_client_access", and after I added check_sender_access above the check_client_access, your suggestion worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`check_sender_access` should be after `reject_unauth_destination` or you could become an open relay.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

See: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions

> IMPORTANT: Either the smtpd_relay_restrictions or the smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameter must specify at least one of the following restrictions. Otherwise Postfix will refuse to receive mail:
>
> reject, reject_unauth_destination
>
> defer, defer_if_permit, defer_unauth_destination

On the other hand using `smtpd_sender_restrictions` should work, so you probably have something else before it which accepts the email.